# Upload Master Page / Page Layouts using PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, page-layout, provisioning

I want to know how to provision a page layout using PowerShell (CSOM) for Sharepoint Online?

Any information,examples etc are welcome.

I know this can be done using SharePoint hosted App as well. I want to know the best practice to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Option 1**

How to add/upload publishing page layout via CSOM in PowerShell:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime")


Function Get-ClientContext([string]$Url,[string]$UserName,[string]$Password)
{
    $SecurePassword = $Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
    $context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($Url)
    $context.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($UserName, $SecurePassword)
    return $context
}



Function Deploy-PageLayout([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Web]$Web,[string]$FilePath,[string]$AssociatedContentTypeId)
{
     $pageLayoutContentTypeId = "0x01010007FF3E057FA8AB4AA42FCB67B453FFC100E214EEE741181F4E9F7ACC43278EE8110003D357F861E29844953D5CAA1D4D8A3B001EC1BD45392B7A458874C52A24C9F70B"
     $fileName = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($FilePath)

     $associatedContentType = $Web.AvailableContentTypes.GetById($AssociatedContentTypeId)
     $catalogList = $Web.GetCatalog([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListTemplateType]::MasterPageCatalog)    
     $Web.Context.Load($catalogList.RootFolder)
     $Web.Context.Load($associatedContentType)
     $Web.Context.ExecuteQuery()



     $fileContent = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($FilePath)
     $fileInfo = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FileCreationInformation
     $fileInfo.Content = $fileContent
     $fileInfo.Url = $catalogList.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl + "/" + $fileName
     $fileInfo.Overwrite = $true

     $file = $catalogList.RootFolder.Files.Add($fileInfo)
     $Web.Context.Load($file)
     $Web.Context.ExecuteQuery()

     $listItem = $file.ListItemAllFields
     #listItem["Title"] = title;
     #listItem["MasterPageDescription"] = description;
     $listItem["ContentTypeId"] = $pageLayoutContentTypeId
     $listItem["PublishingAssociatedContentType"] = [string]::Format(";#{0};#{1};#", $associatedContentType.Name, $associatedContentType.Id.StringValue)
     $listItem["UIVersion"] = [Convert]::ToString(15)
     $listItem.Update()

     $Web.Context.ExecuteQuery()
}


$UserName = "jdoe@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"
$Password = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the password"    
$Url = "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/"

$WelcomePageContentTypeId = "0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF390064DEA0F50FC8C147B0B6EA0636C4A7D4"
$WelcomePageFilePath = "C:\Assets\ContosoBlankWebPartPage.aspx"


$context = Get-ClientContext -Url $Url -UserName $UserName -Password $Password
Deploy-PageLayout -Web $context.Web -FilePath $WelcomePageFilePath -AssociatedContentTypeId $WelcomePageContentTypeId
$context.Dispose()
```

**Option 2**

You could utilize [PowerShell cmdlets](https://github.com/officedev/PnP-PowerShell) from [PnP project](https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP), in particular [Add-SPOPublishingPageLayout](https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP/blob/master/Solutions/PowerShell.Commands/Documentation/AddSPOPublishingPageLayout.md) command.

Comment: I have tried executing the above script. Included my server details,credentials and modified the path of layout to my local path. I am getting error Exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."

Answer (score 0):

I searched for you query on Google and found a link to the code-project site pointing on the same problem as yours.

you will first need to import the Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.dll into power-shell and then follow the steps provided in [this link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/14826/updating-page-layout-and-content-type-using-powershell.aspx)

Comment: I fail to see how your details in this answer is at all related to the question?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I understand how to use the cmdlets. I just want to know if there is a way to upload a page layout to Gallery and associate a Content Type to it using Powershell programatically.